# How to solve the following problem in VC++

Tags: visual-c++

I have downloaded a code when I am building the program, a message window is shown having following message.

Please specify the name of the Executable file to be used for debug session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you download a complete VS project or simply a .cs file? In the last case you need to integrate it in into a regular VS project in order to get it running...

Comment: Look at OP, It's a Visual C++ Project.

Answer (score 3):

It may be that you have downloaded a solution that does not have a specific project selected as the startup project.

If you can find a project that builds to an exe, right click this project and select 
***Set as StartUp Project*** then run.

Answer (score 2):

Downloaded code is DLL (non-executable).